# Red screen in FIVE bytes or less (msdos)

Tags: code-golf, assembly, x86-family

Your program is supposed to create a full red screen in MSDOS. The source of the binary (.com file) must be 5 bytes or less. No wild assumptions, the binary must work in MsDos, DosBox, and FreeDos alike. For winning, you have to post x86 assembler code which can be assembled with NASM (FASM) or directly the hex code of the binary. You can test you assembler code in an Online Dosbox.

Code Example (six bytes):

```
X les cx,[si]
inc sp
stosb
jmp short X+1
```

[Try x86 asm code in an Online DosBox](http://twt86.co/)

[Information on sizecoding for Msdos](http://www.sizecoding.org/wiki/Main_Page)

["M8trix" might be helpful](http://www.sizecoding.org/wiki/M8trix_8b)

[Background information/ six bytes version](https://www.pouet.net/topic.php?which=11991)

Comment: You've created redundant tags (tiny & sizecoding) we have [tag:code-golf] which is for minimal byte count.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks :) I edited the tags

Comment: Why not open this to other languages? (or even requre a red graphical window rather than full screen). Restricting to x86 assembler on MSDOS makes the challenge too restrictive, perhaps unnecessarily so. Competition is mainly within each language anyway

Comment: Also, [don't require a mininum score (maximum byte count)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8928/36398)

Comment: Do you actually know this is possible?

Comment: @JoKing Yes, in fact the SHA256 of one solution is posted in the linked thread. So later it can be verified that the solution existed when the question was asked =)

Comment: @LuisMendo ok i see. Then this is a pure MSDOS challenge, and i will delete MY other posts, if that's how the rules are here =)

Comment: @HellMood No, you don't need to delete them, or even can. The meta post I linked implies that people should not post them, as they would be invalid answers. If any such answer is posted (which is unlikely), you can downvote or flag it

Comment: @LuisMendo i meant MY other posts (that implied you can post other answers just for fun). So i think now the challenge is clear. Please tell me if that's not the case =)

Comment: @HellMood Ah, ok, sorry

Comment: I don't understand. Did you post this challenge just to post your own answer to it?

Comment: @thedefault. This challenge is mirrored from www.pouet.net Over there, somebody posted a reply. Since i don't think he is registered here, i posted it, and hoped that the mark in brackets, in that post, clarified that. Have a look here : https://www.pouet.net/topic.php?which=11991&page=1#c565168

Comment: So... I didn't know http://twt86.co/ existed. This is game changer - can finally post working TIO links for x86 PC DOS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**5 bytes**

*Byte values*

```
0x56 0xC4 0x04 0xAB 0xC3
```

*ASM mnemonic*

```
PUSH SI
LES AX,[SI]
STOSW
RET
```

*View inside a DOS debugger*

[image: View inside a DOS debugger]

(edit:) To clarify, this is NOT MY solution. The challenge is mirrored from [www.pouet.net](http://www.pouet.net), as linked in the question. There, somebody posted a valid solution which i pasted here.
(edit2: added byte values and image)

Comment: That is not 5 bytes. 1 character takes up 1 byte.

Comment: @matt you're right, posting the ASM mnemonics might not be enough. I added the byte values and an image of an debugger view for clarification.

Comment: Posting an answer from an external source without improvement, even if credit the original author, is still most likely copyright violation, and either way it is explicitly disallowed.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms i am genuinely curious how copyright works on 5 bytes of code, when i created almost the same solution BEFORE and published a strong salted hash with it as a proof. (Please see here: https://www.pouet.net/topic.php?which=11991&page=1) Other than that your comment left me with a big grin, thank you :D

Comment: @HellMood Not sure who created what, but according to your own answer: "this is NOT MY solution"

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Yes, someone found the solution i intended to be found - with tiny differences, but basically the same (idea, approach). Funny that a 5 byte version can even differ but there are several degrees of freedom in chosing the opcodes. Anyway, i am not allowed to post my own solution and never intended to do so, yet the solution i posted here representative of the solver (who has no account here) is so close to mine, that i - seriously - wonder how copyright would be applied here. I hope that clarifies things :)